# Allocate struct memory to args for multiple thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, struct, args

The following code runs mutiple threads and if a thread is already launched with the same id, it cancels the previous thread. I use this code to relaunch a timer for a light.

My problem is how to reuse thread params twice ? I must allocate memory for the struct "thread_data" before reuse and before create thread again... This can be done with through the "thread_list" map ? Maybe I'm not asking the right question... However I'm sur right answer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mutex_t;
map <string, pthread_t> thread_list;

struct thread_data
{
    char *num;
    char *type;
    int time;
};

static void cleanup(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_t);
    cout << "Thread Cleaned" << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_t);
}

static void *thread(void *arg)
{
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE,NULL);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED,NULL);

    pthread_cleanup_push(&cleanup,NULL);

    thread_data* my_data = (thread_data*)(arg);
    int time = my_data->time;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_t);
    cout << "Thread start " << time << " " << my_data->num << endl << flush;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_t);

    while(time)
    {
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE,NULL);
        pthread_testcancel();
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE,NULL);

        sched_yield();

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_t);
        sleep(1);
        time--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_t);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_t);
    cout << "Thread End " << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_t);

    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);

    return NULL;
}

void interrupt(string num, int time = 0, string type = "")
{
    cout << "Interruptable " << num << " " << time << " " << type << endl;

    if (thread_list.find(num)->second)
    {
        cout << "Cancel " << num << endl;

        if (pthread_cancel(thread_list[num]) == 0)
        {
            pthread_detach(thread_list[num]);
            while (pthread_kill(thread_list[num], 0)==0)
                sched_yield();
        }

        thread_list.erase(num);
    }

    thread_data td;
    td.time = time;
    td.num = "Ok";

    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_t, NULL);
    pthread_create (&thread_id, &attr, &(thread), (void *)&td);
    thread_list.insert(pair <string, pthread_t> (num, thread_id));
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Start main" << endl;

    interrupt("6335", 5, "");
    sleep(1);
    interrupt("6335", 2, "");
    sleep(6);

    cout << "End main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest allocating the thread data on the heap and free:ing (or delete:ing) it in the thread cleanup function you register. Sending in stuff from the stack is not good. Also, use C++11 std mutex:es and thread primitives instead of posix threads if you want to be more easily portable to non-Unix OS:es such as Windows. Third improvement: Use RAII for thread/mutex primitives instead of manual unlock etc. E.g. std::lock_guard.

Comment: Yes "thread data" must be deleted..... I

Comment: Not if it is static/global or on the stack.

Comment: Yes "thread data" must be deleted in cleanup function passing the "thread data" to the "pthread_cleanup_push" function I think... 
I tried to cancel thread with C++11 thread primitives, I used "native handle" function to cancel them and I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it appears you are trying to use a structure without allocating memory for it:

```
 thread_data td;
 td.time = time;
 td.num = "Ok";
```

This code fragment would appear to me to be in error because no memory is assigned to the variable `td` (except the stack), yet it attempts to assign a value. Thus, once the thread is created and the function returns the memory will be corrupted. For this reason you should never use a local variable for passing data to another function. Normally, I would expect the structure to be allocated some heap memory, for example:

```
 thread_data td;
 td = malloc( sizeof( thread_data ) );
 if( td == NULL ) ... [error handling] ...
 td.time = time;
 td.num = "Ok";
```

Each time you need this structure you should allocate memory for it. Normally, (except in a specialized high-performance application) you should not attempt to re-use the memory.

Also, note that the design is flawed because there is no way to free the memory allocated for the `td` structure. You should actually create the td structure at a higher level, for example, in main(), then when the interrupt() function returns you should free the memory used. For example:

```
   main(){
     ....
     thread_data td;
     td = malloc( sizeof( thread_data ) );
     if( td == NULL ) ... [error handling] ...
     td.time = time;
     td.num = "Ok";
     interrupt( td );
     ...
     [do next interrupt]
     ...
     [after worker thread is complete]
     free( td );
```

or something along those lines.

Comment: The td struct is on the stack, so it has "memory". But sending in stuff from the stack is not such a good idea.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Since the structure is passed to another function it could result in the memory being used after the function has returned, thus causing a fault. I have edited my answer to be more explicit about this.

Comment: Exactly my point, if you read my other comments. I suggested allocating on the heap, and cleaning up in thread's cleanup fcn.

Comment: "Thread data" must be cleaned in the detached thread I think. I don't know duration and number of threads needed. I need to simultaneously launch "switch_light(num, duration)" and cancel the fuction when it has been launched with the same "num" in param..

Comment: @ksirob True, I was just speaking generally. In theory if the data is used through the lifetime of the thread, then it can only be freed when the thread dies.

Comment: @ksirob, if the data used by the worker thread should live longer than the thread, just malloc in main thread, and also free() in main thread, after joining all worker threads, just before main thread exit.

Answer (score 0):

I set "td" in "thread_data" structure. It fails after a long time....

```
struct thread_data
{
    int duration;
    string num;
    string type;
} td;
```

Complet code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

pthread_mutex_t mutex_t;
map <string, pthread_t> thread_list;

struct thread_data
{
    int duration;
    string num;
    string type;
} td;

static void cleanup(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_t);
    cout << "Thread Cleaned" << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_t);
}

static void *thread(void *arg)
{
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE,NULL);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED,NULL);

    pthread_cleanup_push(&cleanup,NULL);

    thread_data* my_data = (thread_data*)(arg);
    int duration = my_data->duration;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_t);
    cout << "Thread start " << duration << " " << my_data->num << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_t);

    while(duration)
    {
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE,NULL);
        pthread_testcancel();
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE,NULL);

        sched_yield();

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_t);
        sleep(1);
        duration--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_t);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_t);
    cout << "Thread End " << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_t);

    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);

    return NULL;
}

void timer_launch(int duration, string num, string type)
{
    cout << "Interruptable " << num << " " << duration << " " << type << endl;

    if (thread_list.find(num)->second)
    {
        cout << "Cancel " << num << endl;

        if (pthread_cancel(thread_list[num]) == 0)
        {
            pthread_detach(thread_list[num]);
            while (pthread_kill(thread_list[num], 0)==0)
                sched_yield();
        }
        thread_list.erase(num);
    }

    td.duration = duration;
    td.num = num;
    td.type = type;

    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_t, NULL);
    pthread_create (&thread_id, &attr, &(thread), (void *)&td);

    thread_list.insert(pair <string, pthread_t> (td.num, thread_id));
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Start main" << endl;

    timer_launch(5, "6335", "div");
    sleep(1);
    timer_launch(3, "6335", "div");
    sleep(6);

    cout << "End main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that structure allocation is bad, but I want to have a function that I can cancel and launch whitout stopping my program.... without joining threads..